# Parse - Get Objects from Relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, parse-platform

I have two tables one with lists and one with cars.

The List table has a relationship to cars. So one list can contain many cars in the column carsInList. For the column carsInList i used the type array.

What is the best query to get all cars from one list? Should i use a unique key for one list and the cars in the list? I think there must be a better way because in parse.com backend i can see that many cars are stored in the column carsInList.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming each user has their own list of cars? The strength of the following method is that it will only generate 1 API request. You don't necessarily need to use PFRelation.

Let's say that we have a class called "List". You can create a column called "userId" with the user's objectId as a value to query the list object by.

```
PFObject* list = [PFObject objectWithClassName@"List"];
PFUser* currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
[list setObject:currentUser.objectId forKey:@"userId"];
```

You can add a single "Car" object as a pointer to the "List" object:

```
PFObject* car = [firstQuery getFirstObject]; // assuming the query has been created
[list addObject:car forKey:@"cars"];
[list save];
```

or you can add multiple "Car" objects as pointers to the "List" object:

```
NSArray* cars = [secondQuery findObjects]; // assuming the query has been created
[list addObjectsFromArray:car forKey:@"cars"];
[list save];
```

Now query for the object as follows. Make sure to use the **includeKey:** method.

```
PFQuery* query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName@"List"];
[query whereKey:@"userId" isEqualTo:currentUser.objectId];
[query includeKey:@"cars"]; // Make sure to include this when pulling an array of pointers
PFObject* list = [query getFirstObject];
NSArray* cars = [list objectForKey:@"cars"];
```

Notice that you can pull an array of "Car" objects from the "List" object via the **includeKey:** method. It should be noted that **addObject:ForKey:** will augment an existing array. You can add a fresh array of pointers to any object via the **setObject:ForKey:** method.

Comment: Thank you Mike E. This works really good. Can you also tell me how to return this query for the method - (PFQuery *)queryForTable in PFQueryTableViewControlle. Should i do it with two querys??

Comment: I've never used the PFQueryTableViewController class but I'd imagine it works pretty similarly to the standard iOS UITableView. Once you initiate a session for a user you can cache the user data via: **PFUser* currentUser = [PFUser currentUser]**. After doing this you no longer need to query for the current user. Assuming you're doing an asynchronous data pull, once you've pulled the data you can just refresh the tableView inside the completion block.

Comment: If this answer is sufficient you should make it as accepted :-D

Comment: Yes for sure i accept your answer. But can you tell me how it works? In the PFQueryTableViewController in the function "- (PFQuery *)queryForTable{}" you have to return a query. And then the objects will be displayed in the table. The problem is that i have to return the query and not an array. So my problem is that i have modify your solution that it will return a query. But i will not work. Is it possible to do it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would just ditch the PFQueryTableViewController and use a normal UITableView or a UITableViewController. Run the query in the background on viewDidLoad or when the user decides to fetch the list of cars. At the end of the completion block for the query, make sure to refresh the UITableView. I have no experience with PFQueryTableViewController so I can't help you in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way to do this, however this will work, and should be sufficient for your needs.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"List"];
// If you want to get a certain list, refine the query :
[query whereKey:@"listId" equalTo:someListIdYouHaveLocally]; // or something.

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *lists, NSError *error) {
    //  If your listId is unique, there should be only 1 list and this will
    //  only iterate 1 time.
    for (PFObject *list in lists)
    {
        PFRelation *carRelation = [list relationForKey:@"Car"];
        PFQuery *query2 = [carRelation query];
        [query2 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *cars, NSError *error) {

            for (PFObject *car in cars)
            {
                // Do whatever you want with that car.
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I like your function. I tried it but i have the problem that the relationForKey is always null. Should i have to add something to the car array when i add it to the list??

Comment: Sorry, I  re-read your question, and this will only work if the cars are stored in each list as a "relation". Mike E's response should work for arrays.